# WordPress site designed with Elementor, pop up box in header pushing page right

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I've spent the entire day trying to figure out how to fix this and I give up. Any help will be much appreciated. Here is the link to the site with the problem: [dev.propadis.com](http://dev.propadis.com)

I'm building a WordPress site with page builder elementor. I've created the header with plugin *elementor header footer builder*. On the header is attached a button with a popup box. When I click the popup box the entire page at the back moves to the right, then moves back on closing the popup box.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the pop up box opening the style: "padding-right:0" is adding to your body from a js file.

Additionally a class named modal-open is adding to your body classes.

I think you should add the following jQuery code in your theme:

```
jQuery('.modal-open').css('padding-right', 17 + 'px');
```

(you can add it inside a ) in the head of your theme)

Comment: Hi @wsoil thanks for responding. I tried this it did not work. I added the jquery to the header via a plugin.

Comment: If you want try this in your css

body.modal-open {
    left: -9px !important;
    position: relative;
}

Comment: Yes yes this worked!!!There is a small shift to the left now but I can experiment and enter the correct left px value.

I think I understood the problem: when the popup box opens, a new class .modal is added to the body that has a left 9px value, which we are negating through this CSS, correct?
Thank you!

Comment: in fact it's more complex, i see that this code isn't correct your problem 100% but i think it seems much better now...

Comment: Yes because The header, body and footer are each moving. The header stopped once I made it sticky, body with your CSS and footer I'll deal it with it later.

Comment: In this case, manually adjusting pixels isn't such a great idea... are we to assume scroll bars are 9px wide on every browser, device and OS?

Comment: In my case, on MacOS both Firefox and Chrome the magic number is 15px to counter-act the shifting. But now Chrome on Android shifts by 15px whereas before it never shifted. Down a rabbit hole.

Comment: Instead, the script or plugin in question needs to do stuff (look at scroll bars, change classes, calculate widths, whatever) rather than end-users massaging pixels. This has been a much talked-about issue for years in web development. Search Google for "page shift when modal opens".

Answer (score 0):

For WordPress, this solution worked for me, so far. I'm using PopBox and Elementor/Elementor-Pro.

Note: ***Do testing in regular browser tabs***. Some developer responsive views may not have normal scrollbars.

In the theme's style.css, add:

```
html.modal-open {
    /* All of this stops the page from scrolling in the background */
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

body.modal-open {

  /* This is the crucial rule to get rid of the page shift when opening a modal.*/
  /* Also, try 'auto' if you have issues ie mobile vs desktop. */
  overflow: hidden !important;

  /* You may want to explore toggling this, depending on your circumstances (page length and/or presence of page scroll bars) */
  height: 100%;
}
```

In the theme's scripts, add:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    /* The following adds/removes classes to <html> accordingly */

    $('#mypopup').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('html').addClass('modal-open');
    })

    $('#mypopup').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('html').removeClass('modal-open');
    })

});
```